# setting up NFS (network file system) on gnu/linux(Red Hat Enterprise Edition)

Tags: linux, nfs

I have two machines, first one running RedHat enterprise linux 5 and second one running RedHat Enterprise Linux 4. I have connected these two machines via LAN. I have been attempting to set up NFS (Network file system), hence the first machine has been made the server and the second machine the client. The IP address of the server is 192.168.1.2 and the IP address of the client machine is 192.168.1.1.

On the server machine I have written the following in /etc/exports file:

```
/home/ram/experiment 192.168.1.0/24(rw)
```

When I attempt to mount the server directory from the client machine using the following command

```
mount -t nfs -o rw 192.168.1.2:/home/ram/experiment /home/ivv/test
```

I get the following error (on the client machine)

```
***mount:mount to NFS server '192.168.1.2' failed: System error: No route to host.***
```

Comment: Maybe verify that the firewall and selinux is set accordingly on the server.

Answer (score 1):

A little more information would be handy:

- Can you ping between the two servers?

  Have you restarted NFS on the server after you added the entries to /etc/exports?

  What (if anything) do you see in the NFS server's logs when the client tries to mount?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out weather this is a networking problem or something related to nfs. A simple netwoking test is to ping to the other host. Ie: "ping otherhost". 
(To make thingns easier, add the hosts to the /etc/hosts file of both computers.)
To test nfs, you can also try to nfs mount the export on the nfs server itself.

ps: reading silent's answer, if it's the firewall, allow udp traffic as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
system-config-securitylevel
```

And try to add the firewall exception

```
nfs:tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your network is totally boned (RainyRat's ping suggestion will tell you this), or else the firewall on one (or both) machine(s) is configured not to let NFS traffic through.  I don't think this is likely given the error message ("No route to host" isn't a common firewall-related error) but it's possible, and worth checking.